# SQL Query - convert UTC time and extract time only

Tags: sql

Appreciate anyone who could help.
I have a table which has date and time in UTC format. I need to convert it to local system time and extract time only. I'm able to convert the time,

```
Convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(Convert(datetimeoffset,R_scheaact.C_STIME, 108), DateName(TzOffset,
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) As ScheduleStartTime,
```

The result I get:
`2019-12-02 09:00:00.000`

How do I extract only the time from this?

I tried this, with no success:

```
convert(char(5), R_AGTSCHEDACT.C_STIME, 108) [ScheduleStartTime]
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the column as `time` to get just the time out of a datetime column

```
cast(Convert(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(Convert(datetimeoffset,R_scheaact.C_STIME, 108), DateName(TzOffset,
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) as time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.